# React: Tie onFocus and onBlur to both an input and a custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an input that users type keywords and a function is triggered to fetch data. The data is then populated in a 'suggested results' div right under the input. All this works great.

I am attempting to make it so when the user clicks inside the input or the div (when visible) at any time, they both have focus. When an item in the div is clicked a function is run depending on the item selected and the menu closes. If they click on anything, not the input or the div, the div should hide, or not show. I've been experimenting with where to place onBlur, onFocus, onClick to no success. Just partials to what I want.

I have a state property that is called 'inputFocused' that is set to false initially, when onFocus runs, it is set to true and that boolean determines if the div is shown.

I've attempted to use onBlur on the input that sets inputFocused to false, which of course hides the div. I removed that and placed it in the div, but because it doesn't have focus, it never runs. Only when I put an onclick that sets the state of inputFocused to false does it hide. But when a user clicks anywhere outside the input, the state doesn't change, onBlur isn't triggered.

```
class Hello extends React. Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      inputFocused: false,
      visible: false
    }

    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.select = this.select.bind(this)
  }

  onFocus() {
  this.setState({inputFocused: false})
    console.log("FOCUS: ", this.state.inputFocused)
    this.setState({ inputFocused: !this.state.inputFocused, visible: !this.state.visible })
  }
  onBlur() {
    console.log("Blur: ", this.state.inputFocused)
    this.setState({ inputFocused: !this.state.inputFocused })
  }

  select(){
  console.log("SELECTED")
  this.setState({ inputFocused: !this.state.inputFocused, visible: !this.state.visible })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onFocus={this.onFocus}>
          <input placeholder="MyList"></input>
        {this.state.inputFocused && this.state.visible ? (
        <ul>
          <li onClick={() => this.select()}>abc</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.select()}>123</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.select()}>xyz</li> 
        </ul>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello initialName="World"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/132164/) that I've put together to show what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever call `onBlur` and you're not resetting `visible` in `onBlur` either.

```
onBlur() {
  console.log("Blur: ", this.state.inputFocused)
  this.setState({ inputFocused: !this.state.inputFocused, visible: !this.state.visible })
}
```

and

```
<div onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur}>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sellmeadog/pwujfmk0/

Comment: Yeah, in my example jsfiddle, I left our blur because it was not doing what I wanted.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what you want to happen then? I thought you were trying to ensure that when the component loses focus or an item is selected the popup `div` closes? Did I misunderstand your original ask?

Comment: Sorry about not completing my original comment! I didn't mean for it to submit, i wasn't done! It looks rude with just that ha. 

Yeah, you are right on the nose. That is one thing I want to happen for sure. And I've been able to get that. I am having difficulty when a user clicks anywhere outside of the input or the popup for the popup to also go away. So 2 ways for it to dissapear is 1. when a user selects an item, 2. when user clicks anywhere else.

Comment: Ok... So what problem is handling `onBlur` causing? If you run the updated filled, you'll see that clicking anywhere else hides the `div`.

Comment: True, but selected() doesn't fire when blur is there

Comment: I found a fiddle that did similar to what I was looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/ur1rbcrz/71/ 

I still need to disect the ref and tabindex relationship, but it does the desired effect of 1. Click input and open a results div if results are present, 2. click in the results div to select a result which will also close the results div. 3. be able to click anywhere outside of the input and the results div to close the results div IF user does not select a result.

Comment: Sorry I missed the selection issue when `onBlur` is registered. I was bored at work and had time to play with it until I didn't and since haven't had a chance to refine my suggestion.